# "Class not registered" SQL Server 2005 error in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

IT recently installed SQL Server 2016 SP2 Standard Edition (64-bit) on our new Windows server. This is the only SQL Server version that has been installed.

Today I'm trying to connect to Integration Services via SSMS, and I'm getting this error that references SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service:

> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "OUR_SERVER" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".
>
> This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

Why is the error referencing SQL Server 2005 when I try to connect to Integration Services? I can connect to Analysis Services, Reporting Services, and Database Engine with no issue.

Regarding the SSMS version, [the "About" dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04jiD.png) says I'm using v18.4, although it also says I'm using v15.0.18206.0. I guess one's the version and the other's the file version.

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using? According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/a0c3e47f-8f13-4df4-a456-fc332a8d7c27/sql-2016-cannot-connect-to-integration-services?forum=sqlintegrationservices) you need to use a version of SSMS that is aligned to the version of Integration Services that you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Because that's just the text of the error proposing one particular cause, which has never been updated -- it doesn't reflect your installed version. The error is actually telling you the client machine you're running SSMS from doesn't have the proper support, and that also has to do with SSIS overhauling the way SSIS is managed in 2016. Ideally you want to use the [new way](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog) (connect to SQL Server, not SSIS, and expand the "Integration Services Catalog" node).

Comment: I'm using SSMS v18.4.